# Obtaining updated TextBox Value in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webpage that contains a databound gridview. One of the fields is a TemplateField Textbox, to allow the users to modify a quantity. I have an "update" button outside of the GridView, which I'm linking to an even that should update the database values with the values from the screen.

I'm new to ASP.NET programming and I'm having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong, because when I click my button, the event triggers, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to obtain the updated "screen" value of the text in the box. I've tried reading through many Stack Overflow pages to resolve this, and haven't found a solution that works for me, so I'm suspecting there's something wrong with my setup.

Here's my aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="uplMontlyMenu">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMontlyMenus" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
            <div class="sectionHeader">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="sectionTitle" Text="School Menus NEW" />
            </div>
            <div class="sectionHeader">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 75%;">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserLabel" runat="server" CssClass="sectionTitle" Text="" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAddRow" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="btnAddRow_Click" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveQtys" Text="Save Qtys" OnClick="btnSaveQtys_Click" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvMain" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
                runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowupdating="gvMain_RowUpdating" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dstName" HeaderText="District" SortExpression="dstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuID" HeaderText="mnuID" SortExpression="mnuID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuMonth" HeaderText="mnuMonth" SortExpression="mnuMonth" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuDistrict" HeaderText="mnuDistrict" SortExpression="mnuDistrict" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuItem" HeaderText="Item Number" SortExpression="mnuItem" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuWeekDate" HeaderText="Week Of" SortExpression="mnuWeekDate" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("mnuWeekAmount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mnuDateAdded" HeaderText="mnuDateAdded" SortExpression="mnuDateAdded" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                            OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure that you wish to delete this row of data?');" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And here's my loop inside of my btnSaveQtys_Click method. Right now I'm just trying to GET the data first, before I use it to determine whether or not the data in the database needs to be updated because it's a new value:

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In gvMain.Rows
    'Check if the value is the same as the database value
    Dim ID As String = gvr.Cells(GridViewInfo("mnuID")).Text
    Dim ItemNumber As String = gvr.Cells(GridViewInfo("mnuItem")).Text
    Dim AmountText As TextBox = gvr.FindControl("txtBoxQty")
    Dim NewAmount As String = AmountText.Text
Next
```

I have the data being stored in a datatable called "MainData", and so here's the code that I'm running in the Page_Load method to either get the data initially or re-fetch it on PostBack from the Session:

```
    If Session("MainData") IsNot Nothing AndAlso CType(Session("MainData"), DataTable).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        MainData = Session("MainData")
    Else
        Dim Query As String = <![CDATA[
                SELECT DISTINCT --Need Distinct because we have multiple customers per district, and we need the customer to get to the employee.
                    --Perhaps there's a field somewhere in a District table that could contain this if an employee can be assigned to a whole district?
                    md.dstName,
                    mm.*
                FROM [NSPrograms].[dbo].tblMonthlyMenu mm
                INNER JOIN [NSPrograms].[dbo].tblMenuDistricts md ON md.dstChain = mm.mnuDistrict
                    AND md.dstActive = 1
                INNER JOIN [NSData].[dbo].[tblCustomers] c ON c.chain_name_id = md.dstChain
                INNER JOIN [NSData].[dbo].[vw_Employees] e ON c.Sales_Rep_ID = e.Employee_ID
                    AND LOWER(e.Email) = '#USERID#'
                ORDER BY mm.mnuMonth,
                    mm.mnuID
            ]]>.Value.Replace("#USERID#", UserName)
        MainData = GetDataTable(Query, "dbNSData")
        Session.Add("MainData", MainData)
    End If
    gvMain.DataSource = MainData
    gvMain.DataBind()
    gvMain.Visible = True
```

I feel like I'm missing some sort of critical element. I assumed that the databinding would just work "magically" so that when the value changed onscreen, it'd change in the DataTable, but I guess that's not happening?

When I try to run this solution, here's what I get. I try to alter the first row from a value of 5.00 to a value of 10.00:

[image: OnScreen]

When I put a breakpoint in code, here's what I see for my variables' values. Note that I'm able to read the BoundField items of course, the invisible to the user ID field and the visible ItemNumber, but for some reason the quantity has not updated to match what's on screen:

[image: Variable Values]

What part am I missing that's causing the databinding to not "stick"?

Comment: You fetch data from session or db and rebind it always on load. So on a postback when click runs, it already has the original data in it. Events fire in this order: https://forums.asp.net/t/1348134.aspx?in+what+order+events+are+fired+when+i+click+a+button

Comment: But if I don't reload the data into the grid, the grid is blank onscreen on postback. I don't want the grid to "disappear" after the button click.